# Kubernetes nginx ingress service cannot serve static files

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

We have created service and ingress files for our deployment below.
However, when we try to reach our app through the ingress controller, we have seen that our static files such as JS and CSS cannot be loaded on the website. Aside from this, when we try to reach with NodePort, we have seen that the app was loaded perfectly.

service.yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: karel-service-1
  labels:
    app: karel-deployment-1
spec:
  selector:
    app: karel-deployment-1
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
    nodePort:
```

ingress.yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: karel-ingress-1
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: 'true'
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.kareldeployment.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/1"
        backend:
          serviceName: karel-service-1
          servicePort: 3000
```

How can we reach all static content of the website by using the ingress controller?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the ingress controller listens on port 80 (and that's why HTML pages are loaded) but they have links that point to port 3000 (and that's why everything works with NodePort). In other words, I suspect that you have to modify the pages to not use hardcoded port.

Comment: Thank you for answer Mr. Slava. Hmm so how can I do this? May I need to fix website pages?

Comment: @thenextgeneration yes, I think that this is what I'd do if I were you.